# Gradle global variable not in scope within buildscript

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have something like this in my top level `build.gradle` (Gradle 2.2)

```
ext.repo = "https://my-artifactory-repo"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username foo
                password bar
            }
            url repo //doesn't work
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username foo
                password bar
            }
            url repo //works
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error

```
Could not find property 'repo' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository_Decorated@718afa64.
```

So it works in `allprojects` but not `buildscript`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is happening because the `buildscript {...}` configuration closure is always evaluated first, so the property is not yet defined. A workaround would be to define the property outside of the build script, either by placing it in a `gradle.properties` file or via the command line.

Comment: Sounds like an oversight

Comment: Unfortunately this is a lifecycle issue. The `buildscript` closure must be evaluated before everything else in your script because it sets up the classpath used when executing your script.

Comment: You can also move the property definition into the buildscript, it will then be available "globally".  Worked for me, but I only have one buildsript configuration, don't know how it would work with multple configs.

Comment: @MarkVieira I placed my property inside of `gradle.properties`, yet still getting this error.

Comment: For me the gradle.properties wasn't a good place for setting this type of variables. What I end-up doing was adding variables in the buildscript and using them from there. For example:

`
    buildscript {
      ext.dependency_version = "..."
    }

    dependencies {
      compile("groupId:artifactId:$dependency_version")
    }
`

Answer (score 12):

You can define your variable as an [extra property](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html) with `ext` in the `buildscript {...}`. This variable is then also accessible in the scope of `allprojects {...}`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        repo = "https://my-artifactory-repo"
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url repo // works
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url repo // works
        }
    }
}
```